# C/C++ implementation of multithreaded boss/workers model

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, scheduling

I am looking for a C/C++ implementation of a multi threaded job dispatcher. 
Boss thread (the main function) reads the job (eg executing msgrcv in a while(1) loop).

The boss reads the new job and depending on the destination dispatches the job to the
corresponding thread. The worker thread executes the job.

I don't have the time to build it from scratch, I am looking a ready solution.

UPDATE: I cannot use boost. It must be in pthreads (Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you're after a thread pool. One can be found [here](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/) (it requires [boost](http://www.boost.org/)). I'm sure Googling for "thread pool" or something similar will yield other posibilities.

Comment: sorry, boost is not an option

Comment: is right that you need a thread-pool. You don't have to use that particular implementation if you can't use boost, but you might look at the code to see how it's done anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Your simplest option is to have the worker threads waiting on a condition variable which gets signalled when a job comes in for them to read.

You would need a mutex that gets locked whilst you check the condition. When you wait on the condition variable it automatically unlocks the associated mutex until the condition gets signalled at which point your thread will have it. You should check your condition again.

You could have one condition variable for each queue or one for all the threads, it depends on how you are scaled.